# How to perform function on a list of dataframes

Tags: r

I have a list of dataframes as follows (dput is way too big even with head=1 so I've had to do a mockup here with str(df_list))

```
$ OC_AH_026C  :'data.frame':    13081 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ chr    : num [1:13081] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ leftPos: num [1:13081] 736092 818159 4105086 4140849 4464314 ...
  ..$ Means  : num [1:13081] 45.183 111.038 162.785 -0.712 83.473 ...
 $ OC_AH_026C.1:'data.frame':   13081 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ chr    : num [1:13081] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ leftPos: num [1:13081] 736092 818159 4105086 4140849 4464314 ...
  ..$ Means  : num [1:13081] 69.6 125.1 156.4 12.8 97.4 ...
 $ OC_AH_026T  :'data.frame':   13081 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ chr    : num [1:13081] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ leftPos: num [1:13081] 736092 818159 4105086 4140849 4464314 ...
  ..$ Means  : num [1:13081] 13 12.5 103.1 56.7 145.4 ...
 $ OC_AH_058T  :'data.frame':   13081 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ chr    : num [1:13081] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ leftPos: num [1:13081] 736092 818159 4105086 4140849 4464314 ...
  ..$ Means  : num [1:13081] 87.114 118.963 184.31 -0.173 171.733 ...
 $ OC_AH_084T  :'data.frame':   13081 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ chr    : num [1:13081] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ leftPos: num [1:13081] 736092 818159 4105086 4140849 4464314 ...
  ..$ Means  : num [1:13081] 29.111 103.142 57.476 -0.712 50.156 ...
 $ OC_AH_086T  :'data.frame':   13081 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ chr    : num [1:13081] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ leftPos: num [1:13081] 736092 818159 4105086 4140849 4464314 ...
  ..$ Means  : num [1:13081] 49.8 81 111.5 47 98.8 ...
 $ OC_AH_088T  :'data.frame':   13081 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ chr    : num [1:13081] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ leftPos: num [1:13081] 736092 818159 4105086 4140849 4464314 ...
  ..$ Means  : num [1:13081] 117 152 224 121 196 ...
 $ OC_AH_096T  :'data.frame':   13081 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ chr    : num [1:13081] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ leftPos: num [1:13081] 736092 818159 4105086 4140849 4464314 ...
  ..$ Means  : num [1:13081] 49.5 102.8 93.6 15.2 103.2 ...
```

I am trying to calculate all the significant scores for each of the third column of each dataframe (Means grouped into bins using dplyr) and if they are significantly elevated they are ascribed a 1 ,significantly depressed a -1 and neither, a zero in a new column for each dataframe.

To do the grouping I have done as follows which works fine:

```
CLL <- function (col) {
col <- col %>%
  group_by(chr, binnum = (leftPos) %/% 500000) %>%
  summarise(Means = mean(Means)) %>%
  mutate(leftPos = (binnum+1) * 120000) %>%
  select(leftPos, Means)}

CML<-lapply(df_list, CLL)
```

I am stuck on then calculating the upper and lower limits for each Means column in each dataframe.  I think this is because I do not know how to reference this column because it is in a list of dataframes. For a non list dataframe I use:

```
UL = median(col2, na.rm = TRUE) + alpha*IQR(col2[1], na.rm = TRUE)
LL = median(col2, na.rm = TRUE) - alpha*IQR(col2, na.rm = TRUE)
```

I have tried to reference the third column of each dataframe as follows:

```
tre<-lapply(CML, "[[", 3)
```

but of course this extracts the third column and puts it in 'tre' whereas I want to alter the dataframes in the list so that the third column has its relationship with the other two columns maintained.

So.....
a) How do I reference the Means column and get the upper and lower limit of each dataframe and then 
b) on the basis of whether the row in the Means column of each dataframe are >upper limit or

Comment: My first step would be `library(data.table); DT <- rbindlist(df_list, idcol = TRUE)`, but I'm not a dplyr user. However, you wouldn't need `lapply` then and even with dplyr your operations should be simpler and more efficient after rbinding the data.frames.

Comment: Thanks Roland. I'm very keen on figuring out how to calculate for this nested dataframe as it is rather than converting it to a datatable. I can see why this is useful though and may use it later in the solution

Comment: Do you know how to write an anonymous function in an lapply call? I guess that's what you're after. Along the lines of `lapply(data, function(x) {...})` and in the ... you can treat x like an ordinary data.frame

Comment: Not sure how to write this. I tried: lapply(df_list, function(col2) {UL = median(col2, na.rm = TRUE) + alpha*IQR(col2, na.rm = TRUE)
                             LL = median(col2, na.rm = TRUE) - alpha*IQR(col2, na.rm = TRUE)}) but just got told 'Error: Error during wrapup: need numeric data'.   Again I think the problem is that I don't know how to reference the columns in the nested dataframe. Perhaps I'm not understanding something crucial here...

Comment: Where do you get your `col2` from? Or is it another function?

Comment: No, your function needs a data.frame as argument, if you `lapply` over a list of data.frames.

Comment: So how do I make data.frame as the argument given its nested in a list....utterly confused..

Comment: sorry @David. should have read Not sure how to write this. I tried: lapply(df_list, function(col2) {UL = median(CML, na.rm = TRUE) + alpha*IQR(CML, na.rm = TRUE)
                             LL = median(CML, na.rm = TRUE) - alpha*IQR(CML, na.rm = TRUE)}) but just got told 'Error: Error during wrapup: need numeric data'.   Again I think the problem is that I don't know how to reference the columns in the nested dataframe. Perhaps I'm not understanding something crucial here...

Comment: `lapply(df_list, function(df, alpha, col) median(df[[col]], na.rm = TRUE) + 
         alpha*IQR(df[[col]], na.rm = TRUE), alpha = 2, col = "col2")`

Comment: Thanks Roland. That does give me the upper limit results for each dataframe so that's great. How do I then extend this answer so that each dataframe has a new column so that if the means are >UL the row gets a 1, less than the LL the row gets a -1 and neither it gets a 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you can do, which is similar to @Roland's answer.

Say that you have data that looks like this (a simplified version of the data you showed):

```
df_list <- list(OC_AH_026C = data.frame(chr = 1, 
                                        leftPos= c(73, 81, 41, 44),
                                        Means = c(111, 111, 162, -0.7)),
                OC_AH_026C.1 = data.frame(chr = 1,
                                          leftPos = c(73, 81, 41, 44),
                                          Means = c(69, 125, 156, 12)))
```

You can use `lapply` to "loop" through the elements of the list like this, which calculates the UL and LL of an input (defaults to "leftPos"), additionally, it calculates a binary column (`res`) which indicates if the `Means`-value is outside of the confidence-interval:

```
df_list2 <- lapply(df_list, function(df, alpha, col2) { 

  # perform all your calculations here
  df$LL <- median(df[, col2], na.rm = T) - alpha*IQR(df[, col2], na.rm = T)
  df$UL <- median(df[, col2], na.rm = T) + alpha*IQR(df[, col2], na.rm = T)

  # -1 if Means < LL, 
  # 1 if Means > UL
  # 0 otherwise, nest the operators 
  # if you wish to calculate more complex conditions
  df$res <- 0 + ((df$Means < df$LL)*(-1)) + ((df$Means > df$UL)*1)

  return(df)
}, alpha = 0.95, col2 = "Means")

df_list2
# $OC_AH_026C
# chr leftPos Means       LL       UL res
# 1   1      73 111.0 72.35875 149.6412   0
# 2   1      81 111.0 72.35875 149.6412   0
# 3   1      41 162.0 72.35875 149.6412   1
# 4   1      44  -0.7 72.35875 149.6412  -1
# 
# $OC_AH_026C.1
# chr leftPos Means   LL    UL res
# 1   1      73    69 22.9 171.1   0
# 2   1      81   125 22.9 171.1   0
# 3   1      41   156 22.9 171.1   0
# 4   1      44    12 22.9 171.1  -1
```

(I hope I got your question right of what you need, otherwise let me know and I will correct the answer).

## data.table way

For the sake of the completeness, I incude a `data.table`-way, which is faster (but gets rid of the list-structure). The approach looks like this:

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr) # for some piping

# combine all listed data.frames to one data.table with another column, which indicates the name
dt <- lapply(1:length(df_list), function(i) {
  nam <- names(df_list)[i]
  df <- df_list[[i]]
  tmpdt <- data.table(name = nam, df)
}) %>% rbindlist

# calculate the limits
alpha = 0.95
dt[, LL := median(Means, na.rm = T) - alpha*IQR(Means, na.rm = T), by = name]
dt[, UL := median(Means, na.rm = T) + alpha*IQR(Means, na.rm = T), by = name]

dt[, res := 0 + ((df$Means < df$LL)*(-1)) + ((df$Means > df$UL)*1)]
```

Comment: OK that's pretty close. Only the <LL  outputs a 1 rather than a -1

Comment: So you want to get -1 in case of Means < LL and a 1 if Means > UL?!

Comment: Hi. I was hoping to get 1 if >UL, -1 if <LL and 0 if neither

Comment: Alright, will edit it in a second. Second question, do you want to calculate the CI over the column `Means`, `leftPos` or a third one?

Comment: CI over the means. I changed it in my code already but guess you might incorporate it in an edit

Comment: Ok, I corrected it and it should get the right result. What do you say?

Comment: Perfect. Thanks so much